# json encode in golang fabric chaincode behavior

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I've seen several articles with similar errors, but none seems to work for me. I've seen the marbles samples, as well as many others, and still can't pinpoint the error.

I'm in fabric 2.x. The chaincode below works just fine when saving data, but fails when reading with the following message:

```sh
ERROR] Error submitting transaction: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    peer=org1peer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080, status=500, message=Error handling success response. Value did not match schema:
1. return: Additional property field1 is not allowed
2. return: Additional property field2 is not allowed
3. return: field1,omitempty is required
4. return: field2,omitempty is required
```

```golang
type Asset struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1,omitempty"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2,omitempty"`
}

func (c *AssetContract) CreateAsset(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, assetID string, values string) (bool, error) {
    
    // convert json input to byte array
    txData := []byte(values)

    // convert byte array to HlpAsset struct
    asset := new(asset)
    err = json.Unmarshal(txData, &asset)

    // convert struct back to bytes
    txBytes, err := json.Marshal(asset)

    return true, ctx.GetStub().PutState(assetID, txBytes)
}

func (c *AssetContract) ReadAsset(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, assetID string) (*Asset, error) {

    txBytes, _ := ctx.GetStub().GetState(assetID)

    // convert byte array to HlpAsset struct
    asset := new(Asset)
    err = json.Unmarshal(txBytes, &asset)

    return asset, nil
}
```

testing with the following input data:

```json
assetID: "3",
values: "{\"field1\":\"123\",\"field2\":\"a05\"}"
```

In addition, I'm not exactly sure why I need to Unmarshal/Marshal. Couldn't I just convert the stringified JSON to byte and save that? I know that works, is it "only" for data validation purposes that this is required?

Anyway, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `omitempty` fields, set also `metadata:",optional"` to pass validation. And you cannot set `json:"omitempty" metadata:",optional"` on all fields of your model. The default Fabric 2.X Go chaincode's transaction serializer does not like it for any reason. If you really need `omitempty` for those fields, you can add any other dumb field.

You can add a dumb boolean...

```golang
type Asset struct {
    Dumb bool `json:"dumb"`
    Field1 string `json:"field1,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
}
```

...or add the key/ID itself to the model...

```golang
type Asset struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Field1 string `json:"field1,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
}
```

...or a document type...

```golang
type Asset struct {
    DocType string `json:"docType"`
    Field1 string `json:"field1,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2,omitempty" metadata:",optional"`
}
```

As an alternative, you can try to override default ContractChaincode's TransactionSerializer (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi#ContractChaincode). I've done it when migrating a chaincode that already had its own input validation from 1.X to 2.X, to avoid `metadata` checks and to return seralization errors in my own format; and may work for your case.

Or you can return a `string` instead of an `*Asset` from `ReadAsset` as a workaround to avoid the check that is causing your error, so that it is deserialized only in the client. In fact, I find not much coherent to receive an `string` in `CreateAsset`, but return an `*Asset` in `ReadAsset`. I would use the same format for both (`*Asset`, preferably, unless you are stuck with your issue).

Comment: Is  "You cannot set json:"omitempty" on all fields of your model." specific to the way the json package in golang handles it, or is it related to fabric?

Comment: Related to the `TransactionSerializer` of Fabric 2.X Go chaincode when deserializing/validating inputs and serializing/validating outputs. There are also some similar behaviours with `metadata:",optional"`.

Comment: In fact, I forgot to mention that `metadata:",optional"` is also required for `omitempty` fields to pass validation (answer edited). But, anyway, the default Fabric 2.X chaincode's serializer does not like all fields to be `omitempty`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442488/how-do-to-with-fabric-chaincode-return-additional-property-records-is-not-allow) where this [bug](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABCAG-34) is mentioned:

> Supplying additional valid data in JSON tag of struct property causes schema to fail.

The bug has been closed for around a year, however, I still experience that behavior. Overriding the JSON property using `medatada` didn't work either.

Using the struct like this worked perfectly:

```golang
type Asset struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2"`
}
```

Comment: You could try raising an issue here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go at a minimum it should be documentated as a limitation